# find holomorphic function $f(z)$ for $u (x,y) = \cosh(ax)\sin(by)$

Tags: harmonic-functions, holomorphic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

Question: [For which positive real numbers $a$ and $b$ is

$u(x,y) = \cosh(ax)\sin(by)$

harmonic? When $a$ and $b$ satisfy this condition find a holomorphic function $f(z)$ such that $\Re f = u$]

---

I got $a=b$ for the condition so that

$u(x,y) = \cosh(ax)\sin(ay)$ and $v(x,y) = -\sinh(ax)\cos(ay) + k$

$f(x,y) = \cosh(ax)\sin(ay) + i(-\sinh(ax)\cos(ay) + k)$

but I cannot form them in terms of $z$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is $\sin(-iaz)+ik=-\sin(iaz)+ik$ where $z=x+iy$.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I got to sin(iaz) + ik but I cannot understand why it is negative inside sin?

Comment: isn't $\sin(ay-iax)$ ?

Comment: oh you are right thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\sin(x+ iy) = \sin x \cos(iy) + \cos x\sin (iy) = \sin x \cosh y + i\cos x\sinh y.$